# Mathematician (non-logician) seeks reference for Gödel's incompleteness theorems

Tags: reference-request, logic, popular-math

I would like to learn more about the proofs of Gödel's incompleteness theorems. I have read and am rereading [*Gödel's proof*](http://books.google.com/books?id=jNzsLjQqnaYC&lpg=PP1&dq=godel%27s%20proof&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Nagel, Newman, and Hofstadter. I like it very much, but I would like something a bit more substantial (but not too substantial). More specifically, I am a professor of mathematics, but not a logician. (If it helps, I am a probabilist.) I would like to read something that is aimed more at my level and is preferably self-contained. But this is purely for my own curiosity, so I do not want to learn a whole new field to understand it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to read [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486348/computability-viewpoint-of-godel-rossers-incompleteness-theorem), which has a self-contained proof of the generalized incompleteness theorem and does not require anything beyond lower undergraduate mathematics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Highly recommended: Torkel Franzén. [Gödel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to its Use and Abuse.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812388) Wellesley, Massachusetts: A K Peters, Ltd., 2005. x + 172 pp. ISBN 1-56881-238-8.
Some reviews: 
[NAMS](http://www.ams.org/notices/200703/rev-raatikainen.pdf) (Panu Raatikainen), [Phil. Math. review](http://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/14/2/262.full)  (Stewart Shapiro) 
and [R. Zach.](http://downloads.akpeters.com/pdf/Godel_History_and_Philosophy_of_Logic_06-28-2005.pdf)

For a more concise technical treatment see Smorynski's 47 page exposition in the *Handbook of Mathematical Logic* (edited by J. Barwise). Smorynski is an expert in the field and a gifted expositor. I recall being highly influenced by many of his expositions as a student (some less technical than the cited paper). Note also that the 1165 page *Handbook* is an excellent general reference on logic for a mathematician.

See also this [Related MO question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34099/the-best-text-to-study-both-incompleteness-theorems)

Comment: that's a terrific book, but does it really go into the proofs of Godel's Theorems, as user requests?

Comment: @Gerry. Yes, I believe so, and my opinion is shared by others, e.g. in the MO thread: Pete Clark and Carl Mummert.

Comment: In that same thread, Bill, Antonio Porreca writes, "No, Franzén doesn’t give full proofs." On pp. 3-4, Franzen writes, "In this book, no knowledge of logic or mathematics (beyond an acquaintance with school mathematics) will be assumed, on the basis of the view that a sound informal understanding of the theorem is attainable without a study of formal logic."

Comment: @Gerry If a reader lacks sufficient background to fill in the details of proofs sketched in Franzén's book then they can find them in the paper of Smorynski that I cited above.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the terrific book "An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems" written by Peter Smith [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theorems-Cambridge-Introductions-Philosophy/dp/0521674530](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521674530)

Comment: That book is recommended in two of the answers to the MO question mentioned in Bill Dubuques's answer.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of good, standard texts that handle Godel's work are Mendelson, Introduction to Mathematical Logic, and Enderton, A Mathematical Introduction to Logic.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend *Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems* by Raymond Smullyan. He motivates well and his style is appropriate for a mathematician reader.

Comment: Seconded here - I have a slight bias towards Smullyan, but while he certainly has his weaknesses I find his writing particularly crisp.

Comment: Isn't that the book that [gave one reader the impression that the incompleteness theorems only apply to Peano arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366560/why-does-g%c3%b6dels-first-incompleteness-theorem-apply-to-zfc)?

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson I think so!

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to proof the incompleteness theorem utilizing computability theory, by reducing it to the halting problem. I think this method is easier to understand, since it just relies on some basic knowledge of the undecidability of the halting problem.

Here is a reference http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/PartIII.pdf

As we speak, Scott Aaronson made a wonderful post about this on his blog: http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=710